# why this angular2 code failed

Tags: angular

```
                        <select class="form-control" #platformFilter >
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="PC">PC</option>
                                <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
                                <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                                <option value="XBox">XBox</option>
                                <option value="XB1">XB1</option>
                            </select>



                        <select class="form-control" #gameFilter >
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="World of WarCraft">World of WarCraft</option>
                                <option value="Left 4 Dead 2">L4D2</option>
                                <option value="Diablo 3">Diablo 3</option>
                                <option value="Destiny">Destiny</option>
                            </select>



                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" #timeFilter >


                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="applyFilter(platformFilter.value, gameFilter.value, timeFilter.value)">Apply filter</button>



applyFilter(platform:string = null, game:string = null, time:string = null) {
    console.log("why?");
}
```

I am not sure what happen with my code
and the error is

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at
>   Object.eval [as handleEvent] (GroupingComponent.html:231)

So what happened?

---------------------------------------Edit: sorry for contain less detail, this is my full code

Comment: what is the angular version

Answer (score 0):

why is it parameter platform:string = null,
Try changing it as,

```
applyFilter(platform: string) {
    console.log("why?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working,

```
   <select #selectedCategory>
     <option value="PC">PC</option>
      <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
    </select>
    <button (click)="getValueFromSelect(selectedCategory.value)">click</button>
```

`

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/HRXjADfiFRTM2TWhaC4j?p=preview)**

Comment: Sorry for contain less detail, I have update my full code.

Comment: @Steveeeeee that is also working https://plnkr.co/edit/HRXjADfiFRTM2TWhaC4j?p=preview

Comment: what is the angular version?

Comment: I think the version should be this "@angular/cli": "1.0.0"

Comment: @Steveeeeee it should work, try updating version and see

Answer (score 0):

It seems on of the below three object is null, check your typescript code.

- platformFilter
- gameFilter
- timeFilter

`<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="applyFilter(platformFilter.value, gameFilter.value, timeFilter.value)">Apply filter</button>`